# Retornar Zero na function MySQL caso consulta seja NULL

Tags: mysql

Tenho essa `function`:

```
BEGIN

RETURN( 
    SELECT valor_desconto AS desconto
    FROM ItemCardapio 
    WHERE id_produto = idProduto AND id_cardapio = idCardapio 
);
END
```

Como faço para retornar `0` caso a consulta seja `NULL`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como seu problema está no retorno do seu `SELECT`, você terá que declarar uma variável na função para armazenar o resultado do `SELECT` e antes de retornar a variável, verificar se a mesma está `NULL` com a função `IFNULL`:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getValorDesconto $$

CREATE FUNCTION getValorDesconto()
RETURNS DECIMAL(10, 2)
BEGIN
    DECLARE valor_desconto DECIMAL(10, 2);

    SELECT valor_desconto INTO valor_desconto
    FROM ItemCardapio;

    RETURN IFNULL(valor_desconto, 0);
END $$

DELIMITER;
```

Uma outra forma de fazer é colocar o `SELECT` dentro do `IFNULL`:

```
BEGIN
    RETURN IFNULL(
        (
            SELECT valor_desconto AS desconto
            FROM ItemCardapio 
            WHERE id_produto = idProduto AND id_cardapio = idCardapio
        ),
        0
    );
END;
```

A função `IFNULL` recebe dois parâmetros, se o primeiro for diferente de `NULL`, retorna ele mesmo, mas se o primeiro for `NULL` o segundo será retornado.

Veja mais sobre a função na [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

Comment: Já tentei.. não funciona.

Comment: Pelo que percebi, caso não haja registro na consulta ele retorna NULL... Mas no caso quero que retorne 0.

Comment: @RafaelSilva, alterei a resposta!

Comment: @RobertodeCampos, é necessário criar uma variável pra isso? Em SQL Server basta fazer `SELECT ISNULL(campo, 0) nome_campo FROM tabela;`

Comment: @bruno101, No caso dele o problema é que o `SELECT` não retorna nenhuma linha, mas também daria para fazer com o `IFNULL` fora do `SELECT` igual nosso amigo @PedroPaulo fez na resposta dele, a diferença seria somente a função.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos, entendi, neste caso a variável serve para forçar um retorno mesmo que não haja nada inserido

Comment: Exatamente, mas de qualquer forma adicionei um exemplo com o `SELECT` dentro do `IFNULL`.

Answer (score 4):

Utilize a função `COALESCE()` que é do padrão *ANSI* (padronização de funções semelhantes para todos os SGBD). Sua consulta não traz nenhuma linha, então faremos uma sub-query que irá nos retornar *null*, com isso, iremos utilizar o `COALESCE` para retornar 0:

```
BEGIN

RETURN( 
    SELECT COALESCE((SELECT valor_desconto AS desconto
                       FROM ItemCardapio 
                      WHERE id_produto = idProduto 
                        AND id_cardapio = idCardapio), 0)
);
END
```

A função `COALESCE` está utilizando dois parâmetros, caso o primeiro seja diferente de `NULL`, retorna o valor do campo, caso contrário retornará o valor do segundo parâmetro.

Comment: A função `COALESCE` recebe um ou mais parâmetros e retorna o primeiro não nulo. Se todos for `NULL` ai sim será retornado `NULL`.

Comment: Eu fiz para esse cenário dele, só precisa de 1 parâmetro.